# How to place a connection string to a json configuration file using .NET Core Configuration framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard-1.4

My solution has 3 project:

- Entity(include Dbcontext,...), target framwork .NetStandard 1.4, project type library
- WebApi
- WebUi

i want to create function migrate into Entity Project.
In Entity project, i have a class TemporaryDbContextFactory

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
    {


        public ApplicationContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa; Password=123456",
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
            return new MyContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

but in here i don't want to use hardcode connection string i tried to create appsetting for dynamic connection string :

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>
    {
        public MyContext Create()
        {
            var environmentName =
                        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                            "Hosting:Environment");

            var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            return Create(basePath, environmentName);
        }

        public MyContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        {
            return Create(
                options.ContentRootPath,
                options.EnvironmentName);
        }

        private MyContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName)
        {
            var configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.AddJsonFile(“config.json”);
            var emailAddress = configuration.Get("emailAddress");

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(basePath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();


            var config = builder.Build();

            var connstr = config.GetConnectionString("(default)");

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connstr) == true)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Could not find a connection string named '(default)'.");
            }
            else
            {
                return Create(connstr);
            }
        }

        private MyContext Create(string connectionString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"{nameof(connectionString)} is null or empty.",
                    nameof(connectionString));

            var optionsBuilder =
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

i stuck in create a instance of this

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
```

the entity project doesn't have any reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
I don't know how to add this because of I can't find it. please help me add  this reference or suggest me a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new configuration framework which you'll like after get used to it:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("config.json")
   .Build();
var emailAddress = configuration.GetValue<string>("emailAddress");
```

You'll need the following nuget packages to be installed:
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`
`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder`

If you don't see it, be sure you're using the right feed. Look at `Package Source` combobox of a Package Manager, it should be `nuget.org`.

Also, be sure that `config.json` configuration file is copied to the output:

```
{
   "emailAddress" : "some@example.com"
}
```

Regarding connection strings specifically, look at this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core

Comment: can you give a name of 2 packages i tried install Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration but failed

Comment: I gave you the exact names: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder`. Why did you fail? What you've tried and what happened?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/ https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/

Comment: but now i got a new error 'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEnvironmentVariables' and no extension method 'AddEnvironmentVariables' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
complier error here : var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

Comment: Yes, you're also missing https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/

Comment: thank you so much it's working well right now, but can i ask you other question. in my Web Api i have already had key "ConnectionString" how can i pass it to Entity Project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155405/discussion-between-beginerdeveloper-and-astef).